# gradle --parallel and maxParallelForks

Tags: parallel-processing, gradle

From the doc of gradle, it seems that these are two independent features?

Looking at the [56.8 section](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/multi_project_builds.html), it is not very clear to me that if tests will be run in parallel when `maxParallelForks=1`.

If these two are independent features, I would expect that tests under one project will never be run in parallel if `maxParallelForks=1`, but tests in different projects (thus belong to different test tasks) may run in parallel (when gradle `--parallel` used)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your expectation is correct, except that `maxParallelForks` is per test task (not per project).

Comment: Is there a way to run tests in parallel in a project?